# BeautifulSoup - Can't find children tags by CSS selectors

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I tried all the solutions mentionned here but none of it is working on my code.
My problem is i only want to get the text from spans tags which are children of h2 tags (and not h3 tags) on this Wikipedia page (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga)
This is my code :

```
import numbers
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
quote_page ='https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga#:~:text=Un%20manga%20(%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)%20est%20une,quelle%20que%20soit%20son%20origine.'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.find_all('h2 > span.mw-heading') 
#not working, results show all spans in h2 AND h3 
for span in spans :
    print(span.text)


#div_span = soup.find_all('span', class_="mw-headline") 
#for spans in div_span:
#    print(spans.text) #or string ?
```

Is someone has the solution today, i would be thankfull to him ;)
(comments are working but taking spans tags with h3 tags in it :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to your goal but mixing things in my opinion and should use `select` while operating with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('h2 > span.mw-headline')
```

Another issue here is that the class is named `mw-headline` instead `mw-heading`.

##### Example

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
quote_page ='https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga#:~:text=Un%20manga%20(%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)%20est%20une,quelle%20que%20soit%20son%20origine.'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('h2 > span.mw-headline'):
    print(e.text)
```

###### Output

```
Étymologie
Genre et nombre du mot « manga » en français
Histoire des mangas
Caractéristiques du manga
Diffusion
Influence du manga
Produits dérivés
Notes et références
Voir aussi
```